# How to exclude jars from an embedded glassfish scattered archive?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-embedded

We would like to use an embedded glassfish for the Server part (EJB 3.1) of our desktop application.

While starting the glassfish server with our scattered archive, we experienced long startup times and high memory usage. We think this happens, because all third-party jar-libraries are searched for service annoations and / or are added to the scattered archive.

Is it possible to exclude the third-party libraries from this?

Comment: Where are those "third-party" libraries? In you EAR? There is no chance to exclude archives from being scanned.

Comment: the library jars are in the classpath of the project, but not in an EAR: we use a scattered archive, so there is no packaged EAR.